# XRDP session disable screenlets

Tags: xfce, xrdp, screenlets

I recently began using screenlets in my local xsession which is the default unity environment. Now I'm also using XRDP for remote sessions on same user account, but unlike in local, the remote sessions are using XFCE4. Now when I login via XRDP it attempts to run the screenlets, but they end up freezing the entire desktop making it completely unusable.

So I'm looking for a way to disable the screenlets from XRDP sessions while still having them running locally. I'm not looking for a solution to fix the freezing issue to get the screenlets running in remote sessions as I'd want to disable them even if they didn't cause any issues.